# Bitrix. Свойства товара/комплектация в шаблон письма на email.

Tags: email, битрикс

Подскажите пожалуйста. После оформления заказа на почту приходит письмо о том что сделали заказ. В нём есть название, цена и количество товара или товаров. Это сделано при помощи почтового шаблона - в самом шаблоне вызвано поле **#ORDER_LIST#**. Можно ли сюда же как-то подключить картинку товара, комплектация - то что выбрал покупатель в ходе оформления заказа? если да то как?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно определить событие которое отправляет нужный почтовый шаблон и передать в него дополнительные доступные поля (макросы). Точнее при отправке события через `CEvent::Send()` расширить массив `$arEventFields` нужными Вам дополнительными полями.
Для этого создайте в `/bitrix/php_interface/init.php` обработчик нужного Вам события, внутри обработчика получите нужные данные, которые должны выводиться дополнительным полем и помещайте в `$arEventFields`. А нужные данные тяните через методы модулей битрикса.